# loop a JS Object

Tags: javascript, object, loops

I have this JS object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "nid": [{
            "cid": "32",
            "uid": "780",
            "comment": "text"
        }]
    },
    "request_status": "found"
}
```

how can I loop through these items to get comment value ("comment":"text")?

Comment: why do you want to loop it? You can get it directly with something like `object.data.nid[0].comment`

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need to loop to get it. Just do...

```
var obj = {"data":{"nid":[{"cid":"32","uid":"780","comment":"text"}]},"request_status":"found"};

var text = obj.data.nid[0].comment;
```

---

Or if there are several, you can use `forEach`...

```
obj.data.nid.forEach(function(val,i) {
    alert( val.comment );
});
```

Or a traditional `for` loop...

```
for( var i = 0; i < obj.data.nid.length; i++ ) {
    alert( obj.data.nid[i].comment );
}
```

---

Or if you want to build an Array, use `map`...

```
var arr = obj.data.nid.map(function(val,i) {
    return val.comment;
});
```

Or again a traditional `for` loop...

```
var arr = []
for( var i = 0; i < obj.data.nid.length; i++ ) {
    arr.push( obj.data.nid[i].comment );
}
```

Comment: thanks, but if nid change to number ? 

{
    "data": {
        "1222": [{
            "cid": "32",
            "uid": "780",
            "comment": "text"
        }]
    },
    "request_status": "found"
}

Comment: @Laky: then change `obj.data.nid` to `obj.data[1222]`. Or are you saying it could be a different number, or a set of several numbers?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just referring to that specific object (or if every object you are working with follows that same pattern), then you can just access the value directly:

```
var theObj = {"data":{"nid":[{"cid":"32","uid":"780","comment":"text"}]},"request_status":"found"};
alert(theObj.data.nid[0].comment);
```

If you want to do something iterative, then perhaps try this:

```
var theObj = {"data":{"nid":[{"cid":"32","uid":"780","comment":"text"}]},"request_status":"found"};
for (var index = 0; index < theObj.data.nid.length; index++) {
    var item = theObj.data.nid[index];
    if (item.comment) {
        alert(item.comment);
    }
}
```

Or if you really want to do the *entire* thing iteratively:

```
window.searchObj = function(theObj) {
    if (theObj.comment) {
        alert(theObj.comment);
    }
    if (theObj instanceof Array) {
        searchArray (theObj);
    }
    else if (theObj instanceof Object) {
        for (var key in theObj) {
            searchObj(theObj[key]);
        }
    }
};

window.searchArray = function(theArray) {
    for (var index = 0; index < theArray.length; index++) {
        var item = theArray[index];
        searchObj(item);
    }
};

var theObj = {"data":{"nid":[{"cid":"32","uid":"780","comment":"text"}]},"request_status":"found"};
searchObj(theObj);
```

Answer (score 1):

Given:

```
var obj = {
    "data": {
        "nid": [{
            "cid": "32",
            "uid": "780",
            "comment": "text"
        }]
    },
    "request_status": "found"
};
```

The direct way to retrieve the comment is:

```
obj["data"]["nid"][0]["comment"]
// or
obj.data.nid[0].comment
```

As far as "looping" through the items to get the value, I'm not sure how a loop makes sense. Are you saying you might not know the structure of the object but you know it will have a "comment" field in there somewhere?

The "nid" array only has one item in it - if this was just a sample but really you'll have an array with more values you can loop through that array:

```
var nid = obj["data"]["nid"], // get a direct reference to the array to save
    i;                        // repeating obj.data.nid everywhere
for (i=0; i < nid.length; i++) {
   // do something with the comment in the current item
   console.log(nid[i]["comment"]);
}
```